# how to "reimport" module to python then code be changed after import

Tags: python, runtime, ipython, overloading, python-import

I have a `foo.py`

```
def foo():
    print "test"
```

In IPython I use:

```
In [6]:  import foo
In [7]:  foo.foo()
test
```

Then I changed the `foo()` to:

```
def foo():
    print "test changed"
```

In IPython, the result for invoking is still `test`:

```
In [10]:  import foo
In [11]:  foo.foo()
test
```

Then I use:

```
In [15]: del foo
In [16]:  import foo
In [17]:  foo.foo()
test
```

I delete the `foo.pyc` in same folder `foo.py` exists, but still no luck.

May I know how to reimport the updated code in runtime?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reimport a module in python while interactive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254370/reimport-a-module-in-python-while-interactive)

Answer (score 173, accepted):

For Python 2.x

```
reload(foo)
```

For Python 3.x

```
import importlib
import foo #import the module here, so that it can be reloaded.
importlib.reload(foo)
```

Comment: Actually, just "reload(foo)" - no need to re-attribute it

Comment: I couldn't get it work. I'm getiing TypeError: reload() argument must be module

Comment: @Burak, Is the argument you are passing to `reload` a module?. eg. You should be doing `import foo` beforehand

Comment: Ok, I got it. I was passing the name of the function. Thank you.

Comment: Note that if you did `from foo import *` or `from foo import bar`, the symbol `foo` doesn't get defined. You need to `import sys` then `reload(sys.modules['foo'])` or perhaps `reload(sys.modules[bar.__module__])`

Comment: However! See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1254379/525169) for a long list of caveats.

Comment: Please, let Python 2.x die a.s.p.  and stop supporting Python 2.x ! A countdown for retirement of python 2.x https://pythonclock.org/ .

Comment: @MartijnvanWezel, yours is the first comment here since more than 3 years ago. Why bring attention to this question now then?

Comment: This method might not override other modules' references to the reloaded module. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61617169/2642356 for a solution to that.

Comment: @drevicko Thanks for your comment, which should be the accepted answer. All other answers included the accepted one, blindly point to `reload(name)` which only works if `name` is a module.

Comment: I'd like to add to the expanded explanation from @drevicko : If you `import SomeLongModuleName as slmn` then you will want to do `importlib.reload( slmn )`

Answer (score 91):

IPython3's [autoreload](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html) feature works just right.

I am using the actual example from the webpage. First load the 'autoreload' feature.

```
In []: %load_ext autoreload
In []: %autoreload 2
```

Then import the module you want to test:

```
In []: import foo
In []: foo.some_function()
Out[]: 42
```

Open foo.py in an editor and change some_function to return 43

```
In []: foo.some_function()
Out[]: 43
```

It also works if you import the function directly.

```
In []: from foo import some_function
In []: some_function()
Out[]: 42
```

Make change in some_function to return 43.

```
In []: some_function()
Out[]: 43
```

Comment: from foo import some_function, not working working under Jupyterlab Python 3.7.3

Comment: Initially, it seemed like `from foo import some_function` was not working here either. However, I noticed that the actual reload does not happen when we call `from foo import some_function` (as I was expecting). It happens only when you save the module file! So after re-saving `foo.py` (even without any modifications), then it was automagically reimported. Didn't even need to call the `import` command again.
So just save your module file and try again, and it should work.

Answer (score 73):

In addition to gnibbler's answer:

This changed in Python 3 to:

```
>>> import imp
>>> imp.reload(foo)
```

As @onnodb points out, `imp` is deprecated in favor of `importlib` since Python 3.4:

```
>>> import importlib
>>> importlib.reload(foo)
```

Comment: Just a small sidenote: In later versions of Python 3.x, "imp" is deprecated in favor of "importlib". Works the same way, though.

Comment: I really wish Python3 were better than Python2, *always*.  But no, they had to eff things up.

Answer (score 8):

If you want this to happen automatically, there is the [autoreload](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html) module that comes with iPython.

Comment: from foo import some_function, not working working under Jupyterlab Python 3.7.3

Comment: @Robert Nowak I ran into this, but it worked when I tried just "import some_function" without the "from foo" later in my code after the original from foo import some_function.

Answer (score 2):

In [15] instead of `del foo`, use

```
import sys
del sys.modules["foo"]
```

to delete foo from the module cache