# jupyter notebook/lab fails on imported function

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I have a boolean subsetting function that works on a pandas dataframe:

```
def operational(df):
    return df[(df['cf'] != 0) & (df['ta'] > 0)]
```

it works well in a script and in a jupiter notebook, when entered in cell:

```
#df = ...
df2 = operational(df)
```

However, if I keep function definiton in `pick.py` and import in to jupyter, things go unexpected. It seems upon import of a module jupiter does not reconise the types of variables inside a function:

```
import pick

pick.operational(df).head()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-374442fd7c0a> in <module>()
      1 import pick
----> 2 pick.operational(df).head()

C:\Users\Евгений\Documents\GitHub\sandbox\pick.py in operational(_df)
     11 
     12 def operational(df):
---> 13     return df[(df['cf'] != 0) & (df['ta'] > 0)]

     14 
     15 

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Is importing something to notebook a generally bad idea? I use jupiter lab, if that matters.

Comment: Do you have another method named `df` in the script you are importing to?

Comment: are you sure you're passing the same `df`?

Comment: @Rahul Chawla - actually, `pick.operational` worked when I commented out everything, but `operational` definition! Many thanks! Will investigate where `df` drops in namespace in `pick.py`.

Comment: Also looks like I need kernel restart to effectuate imports again too. Simply running a cell with import does not seem to import the latest version of `pick` module.

Comment: looks like a have a case for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111640/how-to-reimport-module-to-python-then-code-be-changed-after-import

Comment: @EPo Glad that it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, from the comments it sounds like you were expecting the notebook to automatically pick up changes in an imported script. By default, Python caches `import`s, so most of the time changes to imported modules won't get picked up until you restart Python.

Fortuitously, Jupyter notebooks run on IPython, which supplies a [code reloading cell magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html?highlight=autoreload#autoreload). All you need to do is run:

```
%autoreload 2
```

in any cell, and your notebook should, from then on, automatically pick up any changes in `pick.py` as you make them (you still have to save the changes to disk before the reload magic can see them, of course).