# Mocking before importing a module

Tags: python, logging, mocking, patch

How can I [patch and mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) `getLogger` in this module under test (MUT):

```
# Start of the module under test
import logging
log = logging.getLogger('some_logger')
# ...
```

I would like to do:

```
mock_logging.getLogger.return_value = Mock()
```

However I can't create `mock_logging` before importing the MUT, but importing the MUT already calls `getLogger`...

Answer (score 17):

This can be done by first importing and patching `logging.getLogger` and only then import your `mut`

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock

import logging
with mock.patch('logging.getLogger') as mock_method:
    import mut
mock_method.assert_called_once_with('some_logger')
```

Alternatively, useful when patching more than one method:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock

import logging
mock_method = mock.patch('logging.getLogger').start()
import mut
mock_method.stop()
mock_method.assert_called_once_with('some_logger')
```

Comment: Is it really OK to use the mock_method object outside the with statement?

Comment: Yes, I think it is: the context manager's `__exit__` only decouples `mock_method` from `mut.logger.getLogger` With statements do not create a scope so, the `mock_method` is still in (global) scope and available for assertions

Answer (score 4):

This would require importing the module without executing it first, which unfortunately for you [won't work](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/803386-importing-part-module-without-executing-rest) unless you do some fancy hacks like modifying the parse tree for the module, but you probably don't want to do that either.

What you could do is to modify these import-time reference after the import and replace them manually by mock-objects or reexecute the statements after your mock-object is install, though I know, that this is of limited use.

Comment: One can also `reload` a module, this helped me out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1254379/11163122

Answer (score 4):

You need to import the module inside a mocked context and remove the module from `sys.modules` after importing so the mock doesn't persist in other tests that import `mut`:

```
import sys
from unittest import mock

with mock.patch("logging.getLogger") as mock_logging:
    import mut
    del sys.modules["mut"]
...
```

Alternatively with pytest:

```
import sys
import pytest

def mock_get_logger(name):
    print("mock logger name", name)

with pytest.MonkeyPatch().context() as ctx:
    ctx.setattr("", mock_get_logger)
    from main import app
    del sys.modules["main"]
...
```