# Python3: Why does import function from file only work first time?

Tags: python, function, import

I can't seem to find this question answered anywhere, so...
MacBook Pro OSX Sierra, Pycharm CE, Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (x86_64).

Hi I try to import a function from a file, and it works.
Then I change the function in the file, and the import doesn't work: there is no change to the operation of the function.
I del the function, then re-import from file, still doesn't work.

Example, in the file new.py

```
def new(inp):
   return(inp)
```

Then I import and call:

```
from new import new
new(9)
Out[249]:
9
```

Oh, I want to change the function in the file.

new.py changes to

```
  def new(inp):
     if type(inp) == str:
        this = inp + "five"

     return(this)

from new import new
new(9)
Out[250]:
9
```

Still just outputs the unmodified input "inp".
Same deal if I

```
    del new
from new import new
```

Doesn't make a difference if I change the name of the function (!= filename).

Comment: It looks like you're using iPython. The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254370/reimport-a-module-in-python-while-interactive) might be useful.

Comment: `type(inp) == str` is `False` because `inp` is not `str`...

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, pass a string if you want a string. `new('9')`

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2 this was handled by `reload` command, which is now not in Python 3 by default. You have to import it with

```
from importlib import reload
```

Then you will be able `import new` and `reload(new)`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.
What is the process?
from importlib import reload
from new import new
?

Comment: If you `import new` (importing the whole module is in general a better idea) instead of `from new import new` it will work. I do not think, but I am not sure, that reload allows to reload specific functions

Comment: My colleague helped me here:
1. import importlib
2. importlib.reload(new) # the file
3. new.new(input) # file.function

Comment: Or indeed, as you say
1. from importlib import reload 
etc.
Would have been helpful if I'd have named my file and function different names!