# reload Python module within Jupyter notebook (without autoreload)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have the following folder structure

```
project/
  src/
    __init__.py
    mymodule.py
  mynotebook.ipynb
```

within `mynotebook` I can import `mymodule` using standar formula `from src.mymodule import *`. The problem pops up when modifying `mymodule` and trying to reimport it without stopping the kernel. I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254370/reimport-a-module-in-python-while-interactive) discussion but it is not working. (python ver: 3.3.5)

```
from imp import reload 
reload(src.mymodule) # also reload(mymodule)
```

the code above fails with message `name 'src' is not defined` (also `name 'mymodule' is not defined`). I can't use `ipython`'s `autoreload` because I have no permissions to install it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to import `src` too and then `reload(src.mymodule)`.

```
from src import mymodule
import src
# Change in mymodule
reload(src.mymodule)
```

Comment: Quick note for python3: use importlib.reload

Comment: @JamesOwers BTW, do those magic commands work in Jupyter notebook? Such as `%autoload 2`?

Answer (score 3):

This embellishes James Owers's comment from the **Python3** documentation @ https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html

##### This is my module import, when I edit the model I need to reload it.

`import src.project.model as Mdl`

##### This gives us the reload function

`from importlib import reload`

##### .. and when you want to reload your module in a cell

`reload(Mdl)`

Comment: What if I just load bunch of function by `from MyFile import *`? How can I reload all functions?

Comment: What have you tried? If you've an issue that isn't covered you could make a question.