# iPython: How can I import a newly added function from module?

Tags: python, ipython, spyder, jupyter-console

I do a lot of interactive work in iPython.  Currently, I'm working with Jupyter QtConsole.  Suppose I start with this:

```
from myFuncs import func1
```

Then I go out to myFuncs.py and add a new function, func2.  If I try this:

```
from myFuncs import func2
```

It doesn't see it. Presumably myFuncs is somehow cached. I have read about `reload`, but it seems to only work with entire modules, not cherry picked functions. `autoreload` also seems ineffective here.  Is there a way around, short of restarting the kernel?

Incidentally, ipython within Spyder is fine with files changing while interacting.  It is also unusably slow, so maybe related?

Comment: FWIW, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1254379/4518341) gives a bit of detail and a workaround (use fully qualified names), but no solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jss367 mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60936171/6372685), you can achieve this with `importlib` and `sys` modules:

```
import importlib
import sys
importlib.reload(sys.modules['myFuncs'])
from myFuncs import func2
```