# How to reset\reload env variable when using pytest parametrize?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I got the following project

```
project
│   README.md
│  
│
└───workers
│   └───func
│       │   func.py

│   
└───tests
│   └───__init__,py
│   └───func
│       │   test_foo.py
```

func.py :

```
import os


AUTH_DOMAIN = os.getenv("AUTH_DOMAIN")
assert AUTH_DOMAIN

def foo():
  return AUTH_DOMAIN
```

test_func.py:

```
import os

import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize("domain, location", [
    ("a.com", "a.com"),
    ("b.com", "b.com")
])
def test_me(domain, location):
    os.environ['AUTH_DOMAIN'] = domain
    from workers.func.func import foo
    res = foo()
    assert res == location
    del os.environ['AUTH_DOMAIN']
```

at the moment the second test fail because **AUTH_DOMAIN** is still with the value from the first test

```
# result in second run
assert 'a.com' == 'b.com'
```

how can I reimport and update the env param?

Comment: Simply mock `AUTH_DOMAIN` and test what `foo()` returns. No need to test whether `os.getenv`/`setenv` work correctly - this is already done in stdlib.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can find answer here: [Reimport a module in python while interactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254370/reimport-a-module-in-python-while-interactive). You can reload module using `reload` function in python

Comment: I try it with importlib.reload and did not work for me can you give a concrete example?

Comment: This worked for me, my environment variable `ENV_VAR` was being set in other tests and wouldn't update on a certain test

`import module1

    os.environ["ENV_VAR"] = "value"
    importlib.reload(module1)

    resp = module1.func({}, {})`