# How to make python run the whole file when imported

Tags: python, sockets, import

For context I am making a game, in the game there is a multiplayer feature, when I click on the multiplayer button is works as it imports a file `client.py`, after the first game ends, I need to call `client.py` once again as there a line `client.connect(ADDR)` in the global scope. But python refuses to import the file again, I need the client to connect again as it disconnects after the first game.... Any ideas?

`client.py`:

```
import socket
print("HIII") #This is was there for testing

HEADER = 6400
PORT = 5050
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"
SERVER = "<Ipv4 address here>"
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)

def send(msg, send=True):
    if send:
        message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
        client.send(message)

    msgFromServer = client.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
    return msgFromServer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try to make it a function, like

```
import socket
def run_client():
    print("HIII")
    HEADER = 6400
    ...
```

and `from client import run_client` in the main file.
In this way, you can import the function once and use it whenever you want to use it.

Comment: Yee it worked, but is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: If you really want to "reimport" it, you can try the [snippet](https://pastebin.com/ARQy1GrK).
The solution is from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254370/reimport-a-module-in-python-while-interactive), so you can check it out.

Comment: If you still want that the function will run first when you import the file, call the function in the global scope in the file

Comment: @SiriusKoan I think that is what I wanted to do thank you