# Facing Problem in running a newly written function in separate python file and calling it in a main file

Tags: python, function, import

I have 2 Python files,

one is main.py (main code) and other is source.py (functions).

I import source.py into the main.py and call all the functions defined in source.py.

But when I write a new function at the run time, it will be shown in by the source.py's object but when called it shows an error.

```
# source.py
def fun1():
    print('India is the best !!!!!!!!!')

    
def fun2():
    print('Delhi is capital of India !!!!!!!!!')
```

```
# main.py

import source
source.fun1()
source.fun2()
```

This code runs properly.

When I add a new function to the source.py

```
def fun3():
   print('Modi is India's Prime minister!!!!!!!')
```

If I import source.py again and call fun3() from main.py, It show the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in AttributeError: module 'source' has no attribute 'fun3'
```

I want to know how to re-import the source.py so that it uses newly coded function without restarting the IDE I am using.

I am using **Visual Studio 2017** for development in python

TIA

Comment: just to make sure, you not properly escaping the ' in fun3 is not whats causing the problem?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/1254379/6744133 answer your question?

Comment: @Eumel This fooled me too, but had the module been reloaded, a syntax error would have occurred during the reload, rather than the attribute error shown.

Comment: Yes, My question is solved now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all of you to for your reply,
Problem solved after running following command:

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(source)
```