# Restore np.array after accidentally assigning to it

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter, numpy-ndarray

I was writing something in Jupyter and wrote `r=np.array=([1,2,3,4])`, and now `np.array` doesn't work. I used `np.array=None`, but now it just gives me back: `module 'numpy' has no attribute 'array'`.

How could I fix this without starting a new jupyter notebook?

Comment: np.array is a reference to a function. Therefore, if you assign something to it it will become something else. Why would you want to assign something to it? Are you deliberately trying to override it? Not advisable IMO. In your case it will become a list containing [1,2,3,4]

Comment: I presume the extra `=` was a typo and the OP realizes they made a mistake.

Comment: @JohnKugelman OP seems to think that restarting Jupyter will solve the problem. It won't

Comment: You can [reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254370/reimport-a-module-in-python-while-interactive) the `np` module with `import importlib`, `importlib.reload(np)`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers! It was a typo i should have made that clear! I didnt think restarting it will solve it thats why i asked a question.