# Override imported module

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

Let's say I have:

```
# a.py
def number(value):
 return value+1

# main.py
import a
print(a.number(0)) # 1
```

Then I change the value of my function, and save the file:

```
# a.py
def number(value):
 return value+2
```

And then I import it again but I still get the same number:

```
# main.py
import a
print(number(0)) # 1
```

What do I need to do to override the function?

Comment: How do you run your file? This shouldn't be happening unless you're just running the lines in `main.py` in a REPL

Comment: I'm using Google Colab.

Comment: Looks a lot like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254370/reimport-a-module-in-python-while-interactive

Comment: You should restart your runtime. Because once your python loaded, meanwhile you changes it after that.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have .pyc files , remove them if yes and run your code